# replace text in .onclick attribute with javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

Now I've found a working method like:

`alink.onclick = function(){eval(alink.onclick.toString().replace("textToFind", "TextToReplaceWith"));}`

but I was wondering if there were a more direct method to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you need.  You can do it a lot easier with jQuery but seemed like you wanted JS so here ya go.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var links = document.links;
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        addEvent(links[i], 'click', action);
    }

    function action(evt) {
        var e = evt || window.event;
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); // REMOVE IF YOU WANT THE LINK TO CONTINUE ON ITS PATH
        var link = (e.currentTarget) ? e.currentTarget : e.srcElement;
        link.innerHTML.replace(/textToFind/, 'replacementText');
    }
    var addEvent = function (element, myEvent, fnc) {
        return ((element.attachEvent) ? element.attachEvent('on' + myEvent, fnc) : element.addEventListener(myEvent, fnc, false));
    };
};
```

Comment: can't I just `link.innerHTML.replace()` ? that should be it - didn't think about editing html of onclicks owner at first

Comment: I try to make sure to cover maximum compatibility and efficiency when I post.  You don't have to use all of what I put of course, but the links are accessed through the node list (the first part w/ the for loop is for this).  Essentially no, you can't just use `link.innerHTML.replace()` because `.replace()` is a String method.  If you want it short and sweet you can use jQuery